# Is the language of all strings over the alphabet "a,b,c" with the same number of substrings "ab" & "ba" regular?

Tags: grammar, language-theory

Is the language of all strings over the alphabet "a,b,c" with the same number of substrings "ab" & "ba" regular?

I believe the answer is NO, but it is hard to make a formal demonstration of it, even a NON formal demonstration.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: You should ask that over there at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Shi-  I think that this question is too basic for cstheory.  cstheory is mostly for research-level topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clearly not regular. How is an FA going to recognize (abc)^n c (cba)^n. Strings like this are in your language, right? The argument is a simple one based on the fact that there are infinitely many equivalence classes under the indistinguishability relation I_l.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this uses the Myhill-Nerode theorem, which says that since there are infinitely many equivalence classes under the distinguishability relation, the language cannot be regular.

Comment: Good point. However, it's pretty intuitive that if there are infinitely many distinguishable kinds of strings, an FA would need infinitely many states to handle them all. Still though.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to prove a language is NOT regular is using on of the [Pumping Lemmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

Using the lemma is a little tricky, since it has all those "exists" and so on. To prove a language L is not regular using the pumping lemma you have to prove that

```
for any integer p,
there is a word w in L of length n, with n>=p,  such that
for all possible ways to decompose w as xyz, with len(xy) <= p and y non empty
there exists an i such that x(y^i)z (repeating the y bit i times) is NOT in L
```

whooo!

I'l l show how the proof looks for the "same number of as and bs" language. It should be straighfoward to convert to your case:

```
for any given p, we can make a word of length n = 2*p
a^p b^p (p a's followed by p b's)
any way you decompose this into xyz w/ |xy| <=p, y will only contain a's.

Thus, pumping the the y part will make the word have more as than bs,
thus NOT belonging to L.
```

---

If you need intuition on why this works, it follows from how you need to be able to count to arbritrarily large numbers to verify if a word belongs to one of these languages. However, Regular Languages are described by finite automata and no finite automata can represent the infinite ammount of states required to represent all the numbers. (The Wikipedia article should have a formal proof).

---

EDIT: It looks like you can't straight up use the pumping lemma in this particular case directly: if you always make `y` be one character long you can never make a word stop being accepted (aba becoming abbbba makes no difference and so on).

Just do the equivalence class approach suggested by Patrick87 - it will probably turn out to be cleaner than any of the dirty hacks you would need to do to make the pumping lemma applicable here.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is a little more complicated than that. This language complies with the pumping lemma. I have a formal demonstration of that, so you have to find other ways to prove it not regular. The main idea of the demonstration is that if you have string that belongs to the language, you can split it in the first character and the rest of the string. By pumping in that character you will always get a string with the same number of ab & ba, it doesn't matter if the first character is a a, b or c. If you have any other ideas, please let me know. Thanks and regards!!, Alex.

Comment: Actually, the pumping lemma can be used on the kinds of strings I nominate in my answer. In this case, arguing based on indistinguishability is a little easier than covering all the cases you'd have to in order to rigorously apply the PL.

Comment: @Patrick87-  I just spent about twenty minutes trying to use the pumping lemma to prove this language isn't regular and failed to successfully do so.  I actually don't see how you'd use it for the language you described, since I could always just pump the single character 'c' without making the string no longer valid.  Can you clarify how you'd apply the pumping lemma here?  If I can't figure this out soon, I'll open a new question asking this, since this is really bugging me. :-)

Comment: Hah, I didn't actually try it. Come to think of it, maybe my strings won't work. I retract the previous statement... But indistinguishability still seems like a clearly viable argument.

Comment: @templatetypedef: true, the lemma can't be applied directly but the 'c' is not the problem. Are you sure you got the lemma correctly?